# Showing a Div section to Show/Hide within a Modal

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a `Bootstrap Modal` and I do wish to show and hide a div section available within the modal on Checkbox checked event.

Even though I have matched my checkbox checked logic correctly. It doesn't reflect the same with the implementation. Any method that I can get this thing fixed.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="ddd" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="ddd">
      DDD
    </label>
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#ddd").change(function () {
      if (this.checked) {
        $("aaa").toggle();
      }
    })
  </script>

  <!--Begin the Show/Hide Section-->
  <div id="aaa">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ccc">ccc</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" disabled />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Close `<form>` with `</form>`.  `$("aaa")` id selector should starts with `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add # in the jquery selector. `$('#aaa').toggle();`

You can also remove your checker. If you want to hide it first, just add `display:none` in the aaa div then the .toggle() will do the rest. So when the checkbox is not checked it is hidden then if you checked the checkbox, it will show.

```js
$("#ddd").change(function () {
        $("#aaa").toggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="ddd" />
    <label class="form-check-label" for="ddd">
        DDD
    </label>
</div>

<div id="aaa" style="display:none">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ccc">ccc</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="question" disabled />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: HI yes I did add it.

Comment: Try to put an alert or console.log inside the $("#ddd").change to check if that function is triggered.

Comment: Hi Jay, Yes your answer did work! The issue had been that I haven't imported the jquery script, as I though it would automatically compile with the jquery libraries in Visual Studio. Thanks btw and I have marked the answer as accepted Solution :)

Comment: Nice. Haha. That would be my second suggestion if the alert is not working.